# Alter Table with var from cursor

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I came up with the great idea that to begin the normalization of characters and collate to utf8, I found the sentences that would help me to carry out this activity, but I have to go table by table. Then I thought about not doing a stored procedure to help me with this.

Everything was perfect, I'm even setting the name of the database and I automatically look for the tables to work, but when making an ALTER TABLE I'm generating the following error.

> Error Code: 1146. Table 'ARMADILLO_BASE.tableNameFull' does not exist

Below I share my storage procedure.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `setCollate`(
IN dbName VARCHAR(255),
OUT foundRows INTEGER
)
BEGIN
    -- ###############################################################
    -- GLOBAL VARS
    -- ###############################################################
    DECLARE tableName, tableNameFull VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE noMoreRowsOne BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE querydbName CURSOR FOR
        SELECT 
            TABLE_NAME
        FROM
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE
            TABLE_SCHEMA = dbName
                AND TABLE_NAME NOT IN (SELECT 
                    TABLE_NAME
                FROM
                    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
                WHERE
                    TABLE_SCHEMA = dbName);
    -- set noMoreRowsOne
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET noMoreRowsOne = TRUE;                        
    -- ###############################################################
    -- PROCESS CURSOR
    -- ###############################################################  
    -- open cursor
    OPEN querydbName;
        -- set @foundRows
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS() INTO foundRows;
        -- begin LOOP
        querydbName_LOOP: LOOP
             -- fetch tableName
            FETCH querydbName INTO tableName;   
            -- SET tableNameFull
            SET tableNameFull = CONCAT('`',dbName,'.',tableName,'`');
            -- SELECT tableNameFull;
            -- validate noMoreRowsOne
            IF noMoreRowsOne THEN
                CLOSE querydbName;
                LEAVE querydbName_LOOP;
            END IF;
            -- SET utf8 and utf8_general_ci
            SET foreign_key_checks = 0; 
            ALTER TABLE tableNameFull CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; 
            SET foreign_key_checks = 1;            
        END LOOP; 
END
```

They help me? What am I failing? ... Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only *values*, not table names nor column names, can be filled in the easy way.

Instead, construct the SQL statement with `CONCAT`, then `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` the statement.

Comment: Ty, for your help!